React App running on Docker container | Hot reloading not working
I'm trying to setup Docker on my react app. However I can't get the hot reload and I have to use npm run watch to see my changes
Also my react app is build with Webpack
I'm using react 16.8.1, webpack 4.47, cross-env 7.0.3.
I'm trying to setup my docker files to have the hot reload but I don't already succeed.
I made these command: docker-compose build --no-cache, docker-compose up -d and docker logs kelklope_app -f but when I tried to access to localhost:8080 I have an error 502 : Bad Gateway
So if someone could explain me how to setup it ?
Here's my different files.
Dockerfile:
# Étape 1 : Image de base PHP avec les extensions nécessaires
FROM php:7.4-fpm AS base

# Installer Node.js, npm et les dépendances de base
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nodejs \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    git \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd zip mysqli pdo pdo_mysql \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Étape 2 : Installation de Composer (en utilisant l'image Composer)
FROM composer:latest AS composer

# Étape 3 : Créer l'image finale avec Composer et Node.js
FROM base

# Copier Composer depuis l'étape précédente
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Définir le répertoire de travail
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copier les fichiers de l'application
COPY . .

# Autoriser l'utilisation de Composer en tant que super-utilisateur
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1

# Installer les dépendances PHP et JavaScript
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader && \
    npm install && npm run production

# Configurer les permissions pour Laravel
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache && \
    chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Exposer le port PHP-FPM
EXPOSE 9000

RUN npm run dev && php artisan optimize:clear

# Commande par défaut
CMD ["php-fpm", "npm", "run", "hot"]

docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    image: kelklope_app
    container_name: kelklope_app
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini # Configuration PHP optionnelle
    networks:
      - laravel
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - NODE_VERSION=14
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "3000:3000"  
    command: npm run hot  # Démarrer directement Webpack Dev Server en mode hot-reload
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: kelklope_webserver
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - laravel
    depends_on:
      - app

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: kelklope_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: kelklope_prod
      MYSQL_USER: kelklope_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - laravel
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M

volumes:
  dbdata:

networks:
  laravel:
    driver: bridge

my_file.conf:
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://kelklope_app:3000;  # Redirige les requêtes vers Webpack Dev Server
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass kelklope_app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

webpack.mix.js:
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
require("dotenv").config();
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.webpackConfig({
  watchOptions: {
    poll: 100, // Vérifie les modifications toutes les 1000ms (1 seconde)
    aggregateTimeout: 10, // Délai après les modifications pour recompiler
    ignored: /node_modules/,
  },
});

mix
  .react("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .react("resources/js/website.js", "public/js")
  .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
  .browserSync({
    proxy: "http://localhost:3000",  // Accès à Webpack Dev Server
    open: false,
    files: [
      "public/js/**/*.js",
      "resources/views/**/*.php",
      "resources/js/**/*.js",
      "resources/sass/**/*.scss"
    ],
  });


CMD ["php-fpm", "npm", "run", "hot"] looks wrong. If you attempt is to run both php-fpm and npm run hot in one container this is not the way to do it. It also is not recommended to do this, create a new container to run npm run hot on that is separate from the php-fpm container but still uses the same volume
